# Eclipse - Failed to create the java virtual machine

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having issue with running my Eclipse with the following config:

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
jdk1.7.0_02/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M

# Adding this line, I get "Failed to create virtual machine"

-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1
-Xverify:none
-XX:-UseSplitVerifier
```

The above configuration works except when I add the lines I specified above. What could be the problem?

I am running eclipse from a Windows 7 (64-bit) machine with 4GB ram, although the JDK I specified in the path is 32-bit which works just fine. The only problem is if I add those additional config parameters.

Comment: Well have you tried specifying those configuration options just a few at a time, to see which might be the problem?

Comment: if I change the -XX:PermSize=512M to 256M it works, why is that?

Comment: You're already specifying PermSize *twice* earlier in the configuration. It's possible that it's just if you provide conflicting values.

Comment: -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy may require administrator rights (surely requires under Linux)

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe those two earlier max perm size definitions pertain to the launcher, not the VM running Eclipse itself.

Comment: @BarendGarvelink: Possibly... but I wouldn't put the collision beyond the bounds of possibility, and I would certainly experiment with it. (Having it twice is *definitely* odd.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Error: Failed To Create the Java Virtual Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Comment: That's a config from Android Studio. So, Android loves Windows developers.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There are two place in eclipse.ini that includes

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
```

make it

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128m
```

Comment: I was trying to do this for long time. Only this solution works for me. Now I can even start two instances of eclipse at same time. Performance also seems ok in both instances. Thanks

Comment: If for some reason eclipse.ini is read-only in windows, it is probably a permissions issue.  Editing it as an administrator or modifying the permissions to allow "Everyone" or your specific user to have access fixes the issue.

Comment: With 256 it was working for a long time. But all of a certain it started throwing the error. Your solution works perfectly fine. Can you explain, why 128m and not 256m ?

Comment: Same here, it was working with 256 all the time. But suddenly failed. After making it to 128m it works. Can't understand the reason!

Comment: Did you upgrade to JDK 8 or JRE 8?   PermGen is the permanent generation of objects in the VM. If XXMaxPermSize > JVM memory limit, you'll have trouble starting the process. Since XXMaxPermSize  is ignored in Oracle Java 8, you'll still have the issue even if you've set it.

Answer (score 16):

I had exactly the same problem, one day eclipse wouldn't open.  Tried editing eclipse.ini to the correct java version 1.7, but still the same error.  Eventually changed :

```
-Xms384m 
-Xmx384m
```

...and all working.

Answer (score 6):

it works for me after changing MaxPermSize=512M to MaxPermSize=256M

Answer (score 5):

Change the below parameter in the eclipse.ini (which is in the same directory as eclipse.exe) to match one of your current Java version. Note that I also changed the maximum memory allowed for the eclipse process (which is run in a JVM). If you having multiple Java versions installed this can be happen. The below trick word for me.

```
-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

I cahanged this to,

```
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

Then It worked...

Answer (score 4):

Reduce the memory size to Xmx512m and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Change the below parameter in the eclipse.ini (which is in the same directory as eclipse.exe) to match one of your current Java version. Note that I also changed the maximum memory allowed for the eclipse process (which is run in a JVM). If you having multiple Java versions installed this can be happen. The below trick word for me.

```
-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

I changed this to,

```
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

Then It worked.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my eclipse.ini after non of the above worked for me.

I fully expected the next run (when it looked likely to work) to recreate it so I could compare but it did not.

So I can't tell what fixed it specifically.

an oddity I did have however was jdk 1.7 but when I ran

C:\Users\jonathan.hardcastle>java -version
Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7', but '1.6' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

i got the above.. so I (re?)installed jre 1.7 specifically and that went away.

This was not linked to my eclipse success directly.

Comment: I have renamed eclipse.ini to eclipse.ini.bak and run eclipse - worked OK, then closed and restored the original name and run again and it still works:) all above wasn't working for me anyway, but kind of strange error it was

Answer (score 2):

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

```
 replace with below one
```

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
MaxPermSize=128m
-Xms256m
-Xmx512
m

Answer (score 1):

You can also try closing other programs. :)

It's pretty simple, but worked for me. In my case the VM just don't had enough memory to run, and i got the same message. So i had to clean up the ram, by closing unnecessary programs.

Answer (score 1):

**Just add your JDK path in windows environment variable. This solves in my case**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've fixed it very simple by updating my JDK version. If you don't have JDK installed or not updated, please [Go here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and install/update it. Mostly your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case reducing Xmx1024m to something smaller e.g Xmx512m make it works. So from all the responses (above and in similar other sites), it seems that you may try to massage/reduce the memory size.

Answer (score 0):

I have added below line and its working fine.

-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/javax.exe

-Xmx512m

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

Answer (score 0):

You can do a workaround as below:

Create a shortcut for eclipse and right click on the short cut and go to properties of the shortcut.

In the target box update the string:

```
-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin"
```

the path will change according to your java installed directory.

So after changing the target string will be something like below.

```
D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin"
```

Click apply and try clicking the Eclipse shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open eclipse.ini and replace

```
-Xmx1024m
```

with

```
-Xmx512m
```

My java version is 1.7 as you can see below

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

so i didn't modify that parameter.

This worked for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a memory issue. If I run tomcat with my (large) webapp then try to start Eclipse, I get the Eclipse error. If I start Eclipse first, then start tomcat and my webapp, all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i encounter this issue and try all of the above method but none of them works for me.

Here is another Trick for to solve this error is

i just delete the eclipse configuration file and eclipse start working.. i don't know why but it works.

Maybe this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If Anybody Is using prior version then Jdk 8 update 20 and getting this Issue 
Please Remove the following from eclipse.ini file

-XX:+UseStringDeduplication

As StringDeduplication was added in later version of JDK 8 in update 20
For **StringDeduplication** Clarification check this By Fabian Lange
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/string-deduplication-new-feature-java-8-update-20-2/

Answer (score 0):

I had also entered the path of MinGW complier for C++. After removing it, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several methods but didn't work. The only one that did is the one right at the bottom. I'll just list the other options I tried as well, for reference.

Some background, I migrated from Mars to Neon and copied over eclipse.ini almost exactly.

**Reduce -XX:MaxPermSize and -Xmx**

Like other answers have mentioned, progressively reduce these 2 flags (eg to 128m) and try again. If it still doesn't work at 128m then try other options below.

**Find the offending flag by renaming eclipse.ini**

Jon H's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23763817/4212710) gave me a hint. Delete eclipse.ini (or rename it) and start eclipse. It *should* regen eclipse.ini and launch successfully (mine didn't regen eclipse.ini though eclipse launched fine).

If eclipse.ini did regen for you, then add each flag back one-by-one.

If not, revert the original eclipse.ini and remove each flag one-by-one until you've found the flag that causes an error.

For my case, I upgraded from Mars to Neon. The offending flag was `-XX:+UseG1GC` Removing this flag (and only this flag) worked for me. Setting back `-Xmx` and `-XX:MaxPermSize` to 1G worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after removing **-XX:+UseParallelOldGC** option from file.

Answer (score -1):

Change target to specific installation file
like below
Target:  D:\SoftWares\oepe-12.1.3.1-luna-maf-distro-win32-x86_64old\eclipse.exe -vm D:\delete\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\javaw.exe