# adt bundle eclipse not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

sorry for such a long question,
But Please help with this problem.

I downloaded the adt bundle from the http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Followed the required steps to use it.
i.e.

1. unzip the folder
2. set environment variables
   ...etc
   then start eclipse.

But as i start eclipce, it gives an error:

"**Failed to create java virtual machine**"

Searching google guided me, that i need to change the eclipse.ini file. but nothing helped.

here is the original eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

when i add the line

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

or

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\javaw.exe
```

error changes to

**"java started but returned exit code=1"**

on adding

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

it again gives the older error:

"**Failed to create java virtual machine**"

Comment: similar questions exit on SO, but worked for me.
Following are some of the SO links that i tried:
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577663/eclipse-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine
3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404964/starting-eclipse-results-in-failed-to-create-java-virtual-machine

Answer (score 0):

There are two place in eclipse.ini that includes

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
```

make it

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128m
```

From here: [Eclipse - Failed to create the java virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577663/eclipse-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Comment: should i remove one of the lines. or change 256M to 128M at both places ?

Comment: change 256M to 128M in both places.

Answer (score 0):

I have already had this error, maybe not the same than you. But killing java process, restart eclipse worked for me.

for me vm line =

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server

Comment: there are no java processes running on my system. Some eclipses processes were running. But killing them and restarting eclipse didn't work.

Comment: It failed to create java virtual machine so it's normal that you haven't got java processes running.

Answer (score 0):

Will it make a difference if you use "", i.e

```
-vm
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
```

Spaces in filepaths can usually be tricky, not sure how well Eclipse handles it.