# Starting Eclipse results in Failed to create Java Virtual Machine

Tags: eclipse, configuration

When starting eclipse.exe it gives and error message

> Failed to create Java Virtual Machine

When I click eclipsec.exe then eclipse starts. What is the difference between `eclipse.exe` and `eclipsec.exe`?

Why eclipse.exe is not working now which was working yesterday?

What will be impact if I use eclipsec.exe to start eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine duplicate

Comment: Did you look at the logfile?

Comment: You might want to check if JAVA_HOME changed. Did you install a new JVM or JRE?

Comment: I'm using XP and let Android SDK install in default directory. If I start Eclipse there (~\Program Files\Eclipse) everything works. If I try to use the directory I unzipped the Android SDK in I get the error you are talking about. Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When I click eclipsec.exe then eclipse starts. What is the difference
>   between eclipse.exe and eclipsec.exe?

from eclipse [wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?)

> > You can start Eclipse by running eclipse.exe on Windows or eclipse on
> >     other platforms. This small launcher essentially finds and loads the
> >     JVM. On Windows, the eclipsec.exe console executable can be used for
> >     improved command line behavior.

meaning the `eclipse.exe` find the JVM for you and starts Eclipse IDE , Where as the `eclipsec.exe` is console exe where you can tweak how eclipse starts

> What will be impact if I use eclipsec.exe to start eclipse. It give
>   command prompt also.

No impact as such, eclipsec.exe is for windows only

Comment: what do we mean by tweak to start eclipse?

Comment: @AmitG you add the command line params to exe for starting eclipse iDE, such as you can specify the where to JRE using -vm param, or you can specify -Xmx /-Xms to specify the max/min heap

Answer (score 27):

Open eclipse.ini file and
Change the vmargs sizes to

```
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

It works on my system.

Answer (score 10):

1.Open folder with Eclipse.exe and find eclipse.ini file

2.Replace -vmargs 
by your current real path of javaw.exe:

-vm “c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javaw.exe”

3.save .ini file and open eclipse. It will work.. happy coding.

Comment: this is literally the first answer on SE that actually explains what's happening. This fixed it for me. had nothing to do with memory allocation. Win10 and Eclipse NEON.

Answer (score 8):

In your **eclipse.ini** file

Add `-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw`
below the line `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6`

And then remove `256m` which is below the line `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize`.
It will work.

Comment: just adding `-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Write like below in .ini file and than it will work properly:

-vm 
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javax.exe

Added above line in `eclipse.ini` file(on the top) and worked for me. `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin` This path can be changed as per your system.
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Adding following line in .ini solved the same reported issue in my machine.
-vm {path}\javaw.exe

Example: "-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"