# java has not enouth space, how to increase it?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I need to run a very big task in eclipse. So I changed the eclipse.ini to:

```
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms64m
-Xmx1024m
```

but this is still not enough. When I increase the `Xmx` to `2048` and try to start eclipse I get the message:

```
Failed to create the Java VM
```

How to avoid this? My system has 8Gb of RAM. So 2gb for Java should be no problem. Why doesn't it start?

Comment: You need to configure the Run Task. The config you are doing is for Eclipse only.

Comment: Perhaps your Eclipse is running in Java 32-bit?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine

Comment: Perhaps your Eclipse is running in Java 32-bit? Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using windows.
You can only apply maximum 2GB to a 32bit process. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#memory_limits

I suggest to switch to a 64bit JVM.

But probably as already suggested, you should also configure your task within eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

your Eclipse is running in Java 32-bit that's why you are getting this message

check this link and you will get best answer for it:[Eclipse error: 'Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to allocate higher memory for Heap. There is limitation for this. Please go through this oracle site. This gives you the idea in detail.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf