# Not able to delete android-support-v4.jar in libs folder in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

**Problem**:: Im not able to delete  android-support-v4.jar in libs folder

[image]

**Giving error**:: If i tried to delete it  i get the error as below

[image]

### {EDIT}

- Tried to delete the jar from file system by closing the eclipse
- If i do so  the eclipse wont restart it gives error as

[image]

- Adding manually the deleted jar .... i am able to start eclipse ...
  still error persists AS SHOWN IN FIRST SNAPSHOT again when i try to delete the file!!

Comment: Have you tried from file browser when your eclipse is not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the Eclipse and deleting the jar file manually with your OS file browser.

Comment: Any help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine ?

Answer (score 1):

I saw Eclipse having problems like this (not necessarily with Android development). Everytime Unlocker came useful:
http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

(applies to Windows)

Comment: [+1] for the tool info ..... Please see the edit ....... if i use unlocker and delete the file .... i get the error as shown in my edit