# failed to create the java virtual machine eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eclipse was working till yesterday without any problems but when I opened today it throws an error"failed to create the java virtual machine:. How can I fix it and what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: The first link when I google the error -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine

Comment: Give us details to work with. Which JVM was it trying to create? Can you run that yourself from the command line? Did anything happen in between when it worked and now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the configuration file of eclipse try to change it : so in your eclipse.ini change this :

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m

make it

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128m