# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine issue

Tags: eclipse, jvm

A few moments ago I have tried to enter my eclipse but then I suddenly got an error message saying "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine".

I just need to mention - this is not the "Failed to create JVM" message.

I tried this but it's still keep bringing this message to my screen whenever I try to open eclipse:

http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/fix-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-issue/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Error: Failed To Create the Java Virtual Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Comment: The Question I linked to has a few answers with different solutions.  If none of them help, please provide more information about your problem.  (Without more information, we can only guess ...)