# Updated to Java 8 and Eclipse failed to launch

Tags: java, eclipse, failed-installation

I updated my Java to 8.0.250 and after that I can't launch Eclipse anymore. I get the following message when I try:
[image: eclipse message]

What happened and what do I have to do to make it work again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse error: 'Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and it got solved by installing the 64 bit of java 8 (the automatic installer seems to only be able to install the 32 bit. The 64 bit can be obtained from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html )

If this doesn't help, this post has a lot more info: [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)