# Issue running java program as perforce custom tool

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate

I am trying to run one simple main java program with the help of perforce custom tools , but its giving me below error.

> Could not create java virtual machine

Below are my configuration

```
Application :  "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe"
Argument : "-cp C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin com.test.mapNullInput"
Start In :C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin
```

Run in terminal window is checked

`_JAVA_OPTION` is also set in system variable.

Any idea why ?

Comment: There are quite a few suggestions for possible causes of this problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine

Comment: thanks for the help. But the issue was not this. when I provided the path for application as "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java"  it worked fine.

Comment: So the solution was to omit ".exe" from the application path, because the custom tool was already adding ".exe" to the end of the path for you? Good to know, and glad you figured it out.

Comment: Yes Bryan , It custom tool take cares of .exe automatically.But this is the case only with ".exe". When I tried running .bat file I had to provide the extenstion ".bat" .