# I can't start eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

No matter what I try, I just can't seem to get eclipse started!
I have tried running it in admin, compatibility mode for Win7, adding -vm C:\blah,
changing -Xmx1024m and -Xmx256m to -Xmx512m and -Xmx1024m, and a ton of other mix and macthes. I download a JVM, and even put it in the folder with eclipse. I copied javaw.exe into the folder, but I ALWAYS get the error message, "Could not Create Java Virtual Machine." PLEASE HELP! I have been trying to make Minecraft Plugins for my server.

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krwkv.jpg)

Comment: Install Java. Don't just copy files around.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine

Comment: Elliot, I already installed Java 1.8

Comment: shmosel, I have tried just about everything there. I also forgot to mention that my PC is Win10, and I have 12gb ram.

Comment: Hey I just added some snapshots, click the link in question.

Comment: Is "Could not Create Java Virtual Machine." the full error message? No other output? If so, are you, the user, able to run the java.exe that was installed?

Comment: Yes, I can run java.exe and if I couldn't, my server would not work. and I gave snapshots of the problem, Please refer to the "Images" link in the description.

Answer (score 0):

It could be to do with having 32 bit java on 64 bit eclipse or 32 bit java on 64 eclipse. Make sure that if you have 32 bit windows you're useing 32 bit java and 32 bit eclipse and if you have 64 bit windows then you're using 64 bit java and 64 bit eclipse. Have a look at this link. It explains the 32 bit-64 bit problem as well as other problems it could be.
http://www.ashout.com/fix-java-started-returned-exit-code13-eclipse/