# Eclipse Mars update error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse Neon x64 and OS is Windows 10 x64, jdk1.8.0_73. All was working fine, and I updated the eclipse and now "Failed to create Java Virtual Machine" is displayed. I have set JAVA_HOME and Path variable too. I tried editing the eclipse.ini file, did tried changing -Xmx,-Xms, adding -vm ...java path.. etc .But didn't work. My eclipse.ini file is :

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-javaagent:E:\Eclipse Neon\eclipse\plugins\com.zeroturnaround.eclipse.optimizer.plugin_1.0.11/agent/eclipse-optimizer-agent.jar
-server
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

Please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: Some suggestions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried the suggestions in this post before asking answer.

Comment: I added -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\javaw.exe", and it worked. Previously I didn't add "" in the vm path.

Answer (score 0):

I added -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\javaw.exe" to the eclipse.ini before -vmargs line, you need to remove or comment out -vmargs and it worked.