# Eclipse neon "Could not create the JVM"

Tags: eclipse

We are setting up eclipse neon on Java 1.7 and it fails to start showing a popup with message

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Here is configuration in eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Eclipse Neon requires Java 8, it will not run on any lower version. You can use Java 7 to run programs from within Eclipse, but Eclipse itself **must** use Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Eclipse Platform 4.6, and the Neon release, a [Java 8 (or later) JRE or JDK is required to run Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation/Java8Required).

Answer (score 12):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24508670/3110474) helpful. I was getting this error even after using java 8, So just delete `eclipse.ini` file, but backup first.

Answer (score 1):

There is chance that the current eclipse you have was not completely downloaded. Try downloading again and try the set up again.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error after upgrading from neon.2 to neon.3.  Since Eclipse is ever-changing, what worked last year may not work today.  My experience has shown the VM args to usually be the culprit in this situation, so my solution was to remove the `-vmargs` section of my eclipse.ini file and then restart Eclipse.

In my case it started correctly, so I added the VM args back one at a time until it failed.  The source of my startup problems *this* time was `-XX:+UseParallelGC`.  After some research I swapped it out for `-XX:+UseG1GC` and now I'm back in business.

Comment: By default, eclipse 2019-12 is using `-XX:+UseG1GC`. If i add `-XX:+UseParallelGC`, the error "Could not create JVM blabla" is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [JRE version 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html), as it's required by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

i just deleted the eclipse.ini then it worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

just add your jdk path on the top of your init file as below.

-vm

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/javaw

Comment: this may your file path may not work to him, so tell to add the javaw path like this :)