# Windows 10: can not run Eclipse. Error: 'Could not create the Java Virtual Machine'

Tags: eclipse, windows-10

I have been successfully using eclipse on Windows 7 and moved to Windows 10. I have:

1. Installed jre1.8.0_121
2. added JAVA_HOME and java to Path
3. copy-pasted the old eclipse directory to the newly installed windows 10

Now trying to launch it but there is an error:

[image]

[image]

Here is my eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe"
```

Things I tried:

1. Adding "-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8"
2. Trying things from post [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine) but it did not work (probably because it refers to windows7)

Please advice.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed the [Java development kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)?

Comment: Thanks @AlecC. That worked! ( I did not know it should be installed and after installing it - it worked). Thank you very much! How do I mark your answer as the correct one so that you get points?

Comment: Don't care about points, had a similar issue myself and thought I'd share what worked for me :)