# Eclipse_Photon: "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine" while executing java main method

Tags: java, jvm, eclipse-photon

Please, can someone help me resolve this issue? I've tried solution mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12333879/7415499, however, this also didn't work out for me.

```
Eclipse Version: 
Version: Photon Milestone 3 (4.8.0M3)
Build id: 20171102-1036   

java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

**Note:** The error is not coming while launching the eclipse.exe, but rather when I am executing a main() method

[Eclipse_Error_Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhNYn.png)

**eclipse.ini file is modified as below:**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\DELL\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.600.v20170921-0935
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `-vmargs C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe` is completely wrong.

`-vmargs` must be on a line on its own, If you want to specify a JRE/JDK location you use `-vm` followed by a separate line containing the JRE/JDK path - this must be above any `-vmargs` line.

So:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
```

Note that this only sets the JRE/JDK that Eclipse uses to run. You should also set the JRE/JDK used to run programs from with Eclipse - this is in the Preferences in 'Java > Installed JREs'.

Comment: As instructed by you, I tried executing a 'Hello World' program through eclipse after making sure below two points:

**1. eclipse.ini is modified as -**
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs 
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10

**2. Confirming JRE** is included in 'Preferences' -> Java -> Installed JREs

However, I am still **facing this issue**, while executing any main class.

Let me know if you require more info from my side.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be an issue while tweaking with the eclipse.ini file and my Java installation. After performing java installation and downloading new eclipse ver, all worked well