# How to fix 'Could not create the Java Virtual Machine' error in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When I am trying to compile my code with

```
gradle bootRun
```

I get;

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Apparently there is something wrong with Java.

I have checked Environment variables and they all are set (including Path). I tried to reduce and increase Xms/Xmx size but that did not work as well. Also I have tried

```
java -version
```

command and it gives the following;

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

But when I do

```
gradle --version
```

I get

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

You can also find my whole stacktrace below.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:396)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun.exec(BootRun.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:704)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:671)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse error: 'Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Comment: But this is Intellij IDEA.

Comment: It links to a big amount of answers and it doesn't matter if it is Eclipse/IntelliJ. The main problem still is the same.

Comment: `--version` with two `-` is not a valid option for Oracle Java. Use one `-` instead; try: `java -version`

Comment: Ah yes. I will add that now. Thanks for info. But still same error

Comment: I edited it @Jesper .

Comment: It seems you have two different installations of Java; 1.8.0_201 and 1.8.0_181 which is picked up by Gradle. Maybe mixing (part of) these two installations causes problems.

Comment: 1.8.0_201 is JRE version whereas  1.8.0_181 is JDK version @Jesper