# Java could not create virtual machine and other errors

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10, virtual-machine

My eclipse won't start since a few days. If I manage to get one error message at start to go away, it will be another new one, or another that I thought I'd already fixed. I do not know what exactly I've done so far, but I'll summarize as far as I remember. One thing you should know: it was very much.

I tried to:
1. Setting the -Xms[WXYZ] variable to another values, like 256M, 512M, 1024M and 2048M in the
    - eclipse.ini
    - environment variables
2. Added in eclipse.ini before -vmargs
    - -vm [absolute path to my jdk\bin\javaw.exe]
    - -vm [absolute path to my jre\bin\server\jvm.dll]
3. Changed environment variables
    - I don't know anymore what I've done there
4. At some point I tried something with the JAVA_HOME environment variable, but it does not helped at all.

I think that I've done so far all of these imaginable combinations.
I've deleted eclipse and reinstalled JRE and JDK, I think I've got nothing left.

Here are all of this pictures on [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/vwxA6OH?) itself (because I can't post images).

It were a great help if anyone could help me with that problem.

Edit: The current error message is:
Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine.

Edit 02: Changed system variable _JAVA_OPTIONS from value in picture to -Xms512M

Edit 03: If i start eclipse with 
`[path to eclipse]\eclipse -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin\javaw.exe` it stated that a runtime environment or development kit has to be available in order to run eclipse. It give me just C:\Program as location. However, if I take the absolute path and write it into the eclipse.ini, i get the same error message (Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine.)

Comment: How about telling us the current error message?

Answer (score 0):

if possible remove -vm P:\Programs\jdk1.6\bin line
more details in here [Eclipse error: 'Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine)

Comment: It's not written in eclipse.ini :/

Answer (score 0):

Open the Control Panel
■ Go to System
■ Go to Advanced Systems Properties
■ Then Environment Variables
■ In System Variables, click Add
■ New Variable Name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
■ New Variable Value: -Xmx512M
■ Click OK
That's it, your Java program should now be able to execute properly.
For those interested, Java -Xmx/s is the configuration parameter that control the amount of memory Java uses.

■ Xmx sets the maximum heap memory size
■ Xms sets the minimum heap memory size
See http://www.jafaloo.com/2011/10/30/java-xmx-memory-settings/ for more details on Java Heap memory size and parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but the temporary error message is still there :/

Answer (score 0):

I've done it.

The temporary newest Version of eclipse (2019-03) does NOT match with the newest Versions of JDK or JRE, as one of my lecturer told me.

So I head back to my favourite Version of eclipse; Luna. And I've got to delete all Java Version on my PC.

I have now Java 8 Update 202 on my PC. You can find it at [this link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), it is the `jdk-8u201-windows-x64` (for Win10 64-bit) file.

JRE is included in this Version of Java.

Another zip`s of eclipse can be found at [this link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

In my case, I had to configure the eclipse.ini file again:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

I had to correct the `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=`-Line and had to add the absolute path to my `jvm.dll`, as I had add the `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`-line. I can't tell you if this is necessary.
You can check your Java Version via CMD-> `java -version`

Now I had to get to the system environment variables and had to change:
`JAVA_OPTIONS` to Value `-Xms256m -Xms512m`
`JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin`
and had to add to the `Path`: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin`

I could've set all `[...]\jre1.8.0_202\bin[...]` to `[...]Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin`, but I don't wanted anymore, I'm just happy to fixed it finally.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 10. I upgraded my JDK to version 8 update 211 and added the following line to eclipse.ini **just before** the line containing `-vmargs`:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/javaw.exe
```

It resolved the problem. Please consider using **forward slash** i.e. `/` instead of backslash.