# Java Eclipse Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, minecraft

So, I just downloaded Java Eclipse IDE (latest version) and decompiled MCP (Minecraft) then opened it in Eclipse, fixed the errors then ran it. Then I get this error, can somebody help? https://gyazo.com/bc4ba064b31d5958fed3ca2f5a9a633e

My Java Memory settings are: `-Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M` which leads to the error `Unrecognized option: -Xincgc`. What VM settings should I use instead?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine/46748607

Comment: Didn't help. It doesn't happen when I open Java Eclipse, I have to actually run the app.

Comment: Is this on windows? Does your system has enough memory? I'd advise checking Eclipse startup script to see what options are passed to JVM.

Comment: It's on windows 10 and I have 8gb of RAM.

Comment: So some more information, https://gyazo.com/39e3f139b411f19669cbfb228ceb4fcc these are my VM arguments and it has -Xincgc and when it errors it says this: https://gyazo.com/ce644f48a9547bd9942bfbf6c83fc684

Comment: Wait, I just deleted -Xincgc from Run Configuration and I think it works now! Thank you!

Comment: add info from comments