# Eclipse error: could not create the Java Virtual Machine. A fatal exception has occurred. program will exit

Tags: java, eclipse

I have following contect in eclipse.ini file. Can some one please check and let me know why eclipse is showing the error?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Delete `eclipse.ini` file, but backup first.

Here is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine/24508670#24508670) for reference.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using? did you set java environment variables? Make sure you are using the correct version for the eclipse version you have.

Comment: It was working fine. I was able to launch eclipse till last Friday. All of sudden getting error. I didn’t touch .ini files.

Comment: I am using Java 1.8 and my environment variables are all set. As I said earlier it was working last week stopped from Monday onwards