# Do not know how to get permission to write eclipse.ini file

Tags: eclipse, macos, launch

Right now I do not have eclipse on my mac. The version of my mac is macos mojave version 10.14.6.
I tried to download Eclipse IDE 2018-12 R Packages. It is for Enterprise Java Developers, and the link is here. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-12/r
After i installed. I launched it and I got
[This is the error message I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRTSw.png)
So i tried this
"1. Open the eclipse.ini file from your eclipse folder,see the picture below.

eclipse.ini

2. Open eclipse.ini in Notepad or any other text-editor application, Find the line -Xmx256m (or -Xmx1024m). Now change the default value 256m (or 1024m) to 512m. You also need to give the exact java installed version (1.6 or 1.7 or other).

max size

Like This:

-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
OR

-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
OR

-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
Then it works well for me. "
[Eclipse error: 'Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302604/eclipse-error-failed-to-create-the-java-virtual-machine)
I cannot edit this file because it says I do not have access permission.
How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it under /Applications, put it somewhere under your home directory where there won't be permission problems. You shouldn't need to edit the `eclipse.ini` file, either (it's already set to `-Xmx2048m` in the current release), but you do need to install a JDK, like one from https://adoptopenjdk.net --preferably version 8 or 11.

BTW, the current version is [2020-06](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-06/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers). Unless you have a reason to use an older release, use the current one.

Comment: I put it in the same folder as eclipse-jee-2018-12-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg. I installed what you suggested. Then drag eclipse icon to that folder and then double click it, then same error happens.

Comment: To get the basics out of the way, *do* you have a  JDK installed? And `-Xmx512m -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8` are on separate lines as they were originally, right?

Comment: No. There is no such line as -Xmx512m - Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8